# can i fire a sql query on the table of Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I know this is very stupid thing to ask. But i am not as genius as you all.
if i have a dataset as give below:-

```
adapter.fill(ds,"Login");
```

Now the table created in Dataset is "Login". Now can i fire a sql command over this table like

```
sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select * from Login");
```

Comment: Another way of filter can be DataView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can filter the data table, eg

```
ds.Tables["Login"].Select("ID=1 AND ID2=3"); // sample expression
```

more on this link

- [Filtering and Sorting in Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ay5y4w0(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it as follow

```
dataset ds=new Dataset

    datatable dt=ds.table[0].select(" select * from tablename")

    or

    datatable dt=ds.table["tablename"].select(" select * from tablename")
```

Comment: can i also used parameterised query in it like: "Select Name from Login where ID = @id". If yes, then how can i define that id parameter is coming from Textbox1.text

Comment: yes you can do it  .select(select * from tablename where ID='" textbox.text "' ")